# I am trying Spring MVC and when I add @Autowired in my controller class I get following error:

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

```xml
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.webstore.domain" />
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Webstore"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="password"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'productRepository'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'productRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {}

```java
package com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.packt.webstore.domain.Product;
import com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository;

@Repository
public class ProductRepositoryImpl implements ProductRepository {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate=new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        Map<String, Object>params=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        List<Product>result=jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS", params, new ProductMapper());
        return result;
    }

    private static final class ProductMapper implements org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper<Product> {
        public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs,int rownum) throws SQLException{
            Product product=new Product();
            product.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            return product;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt"/>

     <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
     p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

```java
package com.packt.webstore.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.ProductRepository;

@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;


    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public String list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("products",productRepository.getAllProducts());
        return "products";
    }
}
```

Comment: Error says, you're missing a datasource...

Comment: If you are developing this from scratch, please please do not use `XML` - use the spring DSL to create beans and such.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you din't configure `data-source` in xml file

try to add below configuration in xml file

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdbname" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: i just added jdbc-confif file look into it.

Comment: why there is two xml file try to have only one xml file

Comment: Yeah when i added datasource in spring-servlet xml file it worked.But previously it worked for 2 XML files.Can u explain why it happened?

Comment: Thanks in advance

Comment: without seeing code it is difficult to tell how you configure your xml file but if you want than follow - https://mkyong.com/spring/load-multiple-spring-bean-configuration-file/ this

Comment: Try to use only annotation configure for spring , you don't need XML in future everything can achieve in annotation it self

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.Have a Good Day !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define DataSource bean in your XML file then only use can use @Autowired annotation to configure that bean or you can use @Autowired annotation in the following way:

@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

Comment: I just seperated jdbc configuration in another xml file so that it is easy to use.